# Model compatibility for older Blender version

Tags: modeling, import, append, compatibility

I have a set of models inside a .blend file, they were made in Blender3.5.
When trying to import the model into Blender 3.4- blender just crashes.
Is there a way to get the model into the older version without having to export as an fbx etc. ?
Thanks!

Comment: Blender files are not guaranteed to be backward compatible. You could try File > Append... in version 3.4, select your 3.5 Blend file then appending the meshes. I guess the main incomapatibility is likely to be due to geometry nodes and possibly physics.